# Setting up ChartKick - Ruby beginner

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, chartkick

After reading http://chartkick.com/ I've tried to add chart to my website
Gemfile:

```
...  
gem 'chartkick'
...
```

index.html.erb:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "//www.google.com/jsapi", "chartkick" %>
<%= pie_chart({"Football" => 10, "Basketball" => 5}) %>
<h1>Hello, Rails!</h1>
```

assets/javascript/application.js:

```
//= require chartkick
//= require jsapi
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

But all I've got is:

> undefined method `pie_chart' for #<#:0x4e49bd8>

I use chartkick (1.2.4), ruby(1.9.3), rails (4.1.0). What should I do?

Comment: I would need to look into chartkick further if this isn't the fix, but restart your Rails server and try again.

Comment: @Justin hahaha, always the simple things, why don't you post that as an answer so people don't stumble across this question and think it's unsolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would need to look into chartkick further if this isn't the fix, but restart your Rails server and try again.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, for Chartkick to work I had to put the:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "//www.google.com/jsapi", "chartkick" %>
```

in the the application.html.erb file only not the index file, under the head attribute

```
<head> 
   ...
   <%= javascript_include_tag "//www.google.com/jsapi", "chartkick" %> 
</head>
```

And it was then usable in the whole application, we also found it to be more reliable when it was in the application.html.erb file.